# headache with "where" condition in statement sended to SQL

Tags: java, sql, database-connection, where-clause

when I send statement to SQL,netbeans does not recognize ? to replace it with strings,int. I suggest, synatax mistake?

Here:

```
         Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement prepStmt = null;

    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://FIO\\SQLEXPRESS;" +
        "databaseName=Feedback;integratedSecurity=true";

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);




                    String sqlStmt = "SELECT SubjectName, Semester, Year, TrainerFirstName, TrainerLastName, StudentFirstName,StudentLastName, Answer FROM Feedback.dbo."+quest+" WHERE TrainerFirstName=? AND TrainerLastName=? AND Semester=? AND Year=?";
        //String sqlStmt = "SELECT SubjectName FROM Feedback.dbo."+quest;
                    System.out.println("SQL Statement:\n\t" + sqlStmt);
        prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStmt);

        prepStmt.setString(1,ffname);
                    prepStmt.setString(2,llname);
                    prepStmt.setInt(3,sem);
                    prepStmt.setInt(4,yea);


        rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {

                        System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + rs.getInt(2)+rs.getInt(3)+rs.getString(4)+rs.getString(5)+rs.getString(6)+rs.getString(7)+rs.getInt(8));
                         //System.out.println(rs.getString(1));


                        /*String id = rs.getString("id");
            String firstName = rs.getString("first_name");
            String lastName = rs.getString("last_name");
            System.out.println("ID: " + id + ", First Name: " + firstName + ", Last Name: " + lastName);*/
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException | SQLException e) {
           }
```

If it is run, it print:

SQL Statement:
    SELECT SubjectName, Semester, Year, TrainerFirstName, TrainerLastName, StudentFirstName,StudentLastName, Answer FROM Feedback.dbo.Question1 WHERE TrainerFirstName=? AND TrainerLastName=? AND Semester=? AND Year=?
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 19 seconds)

Where ? werent replace with ffname,llname and so on..:/

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT SubjectName, Semester, Year, TrainerFirstName, TrainerLastName,
       StudentFirstName,StudentLastName, Answer
FROM Feedback.dbo.Question1
WHERE TrainerFirstName=? AND TrainerLastName=? AND Semester=? AND Year=?;
```

You appear to be using SQL Server (the `dbo`).  `Year` is a reserved word in SQL Server, so try:

```
SELECT SubjectName, Semester, [Year], TrainerFirstName, TrainerLastName,
       StudentFirstName,StudentLastName, Answer
FROM Feedback.dbo.Question1
WHERE TrainerFirstName=? AND TrainerLastName=? AND Semester=? AND [Year]=?;
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) is a list of reserved words.